# Usage of declarative transactionmanagement for two database instances with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, sqlite, spring.net, declarative

I am searching for a solution, to use Spring (V1.3.2) and NHibernate (V3.2.0) together with the declarative transactionmanagement of Spring to communicate with two independent SQLite database instances.

Currently I can read and write from/to both database instances but the transaction management only works for one database (DbProvider_DB1).

The „why“ is clear for me, but how can I use the declarative transaction management for both databases? Do I need two transaction manager? If yes, how can I define a second one and use it?

Here is my configuration, nothing strange but for the sake of completeness:

---

### dao.xml

```
<tx:attribute-driven />

<!-- Datenbankprovider -->
<db:provider id="DbProvider_DB1" provider="SQLite-1.0.72" connectionString="Data Source=db1.db3;Version=3;New=False;" />
<db:provider id="DbProvider_DB2" provider="SQLite-1.0.72" connectionString="Data Source=db2.db3;Version=3;New=False;" />

<!-- SessionFactories -->
<object id="SessionFactory" abstract="true" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject, Spring.Data.NHibernate32">
  <property name="HibernateProperties">
    <dictionary>...</dictionary>
  </property>
  <property name="ExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory" value="true" />
</object>

<object id="SessionFactory_DB1" parent="SessionFactory" >
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider_DB1" />
</object>

<object id="SessionFactory_DB2" parent="SessionFactory" >
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider_DB2" />
</object>

<!-- Transactionmanager -->  
<object id="transactionManager" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, Spring.Data.NHibernate32">
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider_DB1"/>
  <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory_DB1"/>
  <property name="TransactionSynchronization" value="Always"/>
</object>

<!-- Data Access Objects -->
<object id="Dao_DB1" type="Dao1, Dao">
  <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory_DB1" />
</object>

<object id="Dao_DB2" type="Dao2, Dao">
  <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory_DB2" />
</object>
```

---

### Dao

```
[Transaction]
public TEntity Save( TEntity entity )
{
  CurrentSession.Save( entity );
  return entity;
}
```

Thanx

Comment: I thought I read an article on the spring.net forum that stated it wasn't possible to use declarative transaction management when using more than one database, because spring is not able to determine whicht transaction manager to use from the attribute only.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the TxScopeTransactionManager instaed of HibernateTransactionManager.

```
<object id="transactionManager" type="Spring.Data.Core.TxScopeTransactionManager, Spring.Data">
    <property name="TransactionSynchronization" value="Always"/>
</object>
```